# Запрет повторной регистрации пользователя

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server

Регистрация пользователя в WinForms через БД.

Не могу сообразить, сделал регистрацию в WinForms через базу данных SQL server management studio, нужно сделать так, чтобы нельзя было регистрировать те данные, которые уже были зарегистрированы и лежат в базе данных, помогите!

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text == "" || textBox2.Text == "" || textBox3.Text == "" || textBox4.Text == "" || textBox5.Text == "" || textBox6.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Пожалуйста, заполните все поля для регистрации!!!");
    }
    else
    { SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=sql2016;Initial Catalog=Stolovka;Integrated Security=True;");
        con.Open();
        string str = "insert into Users(Login,Password,Name,Surname,Patronymic,Telefon) values ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "','" + textBox6.Text + "')";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Пользователь зарегистрирован!!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Сделайте [Unique constraint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-unique-constraints?view=sql-server-2017) на нужные поля. При вставке ловите возможное исключение.

Answer (score 0):

Все просто: Вам следует сделать запрос (select) в бд с условием по тем полям которые не должны повторяться. Если запрос возвращает что-либо, следовательно такие данные уже были введены ))

Искренне надеюсь, что данный код лишь учебный и не используется в бою, иначе налетят коршуны и заклюют Вас ))

Comment: Ага, клюну разок https://samsonych.livejournal.com/5472.html